# Can't do initial push to Heroku - what's wrong?

Tags: git, heroku

After calling heroku create [name] I am trying to do a git push heroku master and I get the following errors:

```
git@heroku.com: No such file or directory
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've looked around and can't figure out what is causing this. I can SSH -v git@heroku.com get "Entering interactive session." I can push to other remotes. I have verified with git remote -v that the proper Heroku remote is present. These are my remotes:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:akicon.git (fetch) 
heroku  git@heroku.com:akicon.git (push)
```

What should I do? I've tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling. In fact, that's how this problem seems to have come about in the first place.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your git remote look like?

Comment: Updated the question to include this info.

Comment: Perhaps your version of git is an old one?

Comment: I tried uninstalling everything, deleting the ssh/git config folders, and starting over. I installed RailsInstaller followed by Heroku Toolbelt (which, because I have git already, doesn't install it). I regenerated new keys using heroku keys:clear heroku keys:add and it still is acting up.

Comment: When I go to http://akicon.herokuapp.com/ I get `No such app`.  Are you sure that is the right app name?

Comment: Well, yeah, I deleted it...here, try again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17886/discussion-between-ed-altorfer-and-james-ward)

Answer (score 2):

You probably set your git remote like this:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com
```

That's the way that I can reproduce this problem.

To fix this problem, remove the remote and add the correct URL:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:[your-heroku-application's name].git
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have verified with git remote -v that the proper Heroku remote is present.

Comment: What Ryan is trying to say is you probably have set your remote wrong by typing `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com`. The reason Heroku/Git is complaining is because you have not specified the correct repo to point to.

Comment: I edited the question to include the information I see when I test git remote -v:

heroku  git@heroku.com:akicon.git (fetch) 
heroku  git@heroku.com:akicon.git (push)

Comment: I didn't add them manually - I used heroku create to do it. Trying ssh-agent git@heroku.com yields the same file not found error.